# How to Create Magento Dataflow advanced profiles during extension installation in Magento 1.9.x?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, dataflow

Can anyone please tell me How to Create New Magento Dataflow advanced profiles during extension installation in Magento 1.9.x?

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. Are you looking to create a module that as part of it's set-up scripts will create dataflow profile?

Comment: @david, Yes I am trying to do that.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a data installer. To learn more about the basics of those please check out this [Inchoo Article](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/).

Now for the business end of the data installer; we create a new file in the module root `data/my_module/install-1.0.0.php`

and create a Dataflow Profile for installation

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * Dataflow profile data
 */
Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile')->setData([
    'name'         => 'Import OrderAdd items',
    'actions_xml'  => '<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[csvfile.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>
<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter">my_module/dataflow_adapters_import</var>
    <var name="method">saveRow</var>
</action>',
    'gui_data'     => '',
    'direction'    => 'import',
    'entity_type'  => '',
    'store_id'     => 0,
    'data_transfer'=> 'file'
])->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```