# Dataflow import via script

Tags: magento-1.9, php, dataflow

Can anyone please tell  me How to create new Advance Dataflow Profile via script during extension installation?

I asked earlier also but no response: [How to Create Magento Dataflow advanced profiles during extension installation in Magento 1.9.x?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136858/how-to-create-magento-dataflow-advanced-profiles-during-extension-installation-i)

Thanks

Comment: please give us more detail and provide what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi, I have created a custom module. So for that module I want to Import the CSV file using Advanced Dataflow profiles. I have implemented that functionality too in my module. Now, the problem is for now, I have created the Dataflow profiles by myself from admin panel. But I want that those Dataflow profiles will automatically created when extension installed so that Customer doesnt need to create them by admin panel.
I have found a script (https://www.ayasoftware.com/how-create-magento-dataflow-advanced-profiles-programmatically) but I don't know how to run this during extension installation.